jsdoc @example from another file
I want to use another file to document my function so I could enjoy full syntax highlighting, error report, and type safety in example. currently I just manually coping it over when i change the example, and it's annoying.
so I want something like that:
//index.js

/**
 * @example import("index.example.js)
 */
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

//index.example.js

// This is an example of how to use the add function
const result = add(1, 2);
console.log(result); // Outputs: 3

should be equivalent to
/**
 * @example
 * // This is an example of how to use the add function
 * const result = add(1, 2);
 * console.log(result); // Outputs: 3
 */
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

I could also add extra step to my build process and use some template engine like jinja but it feels overengineering for that.
An equally valid alternative would be a vs code extension/WebStorm setting that completely make examples in jsdoc to be fully valid javascript/typescript code with syntax highlighting and error report.
I searched for similar questions but couldn't find an answer.
